# Angular 4 ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I need to hide and show a textbox based on the value selected in the drop-down.

This is already done in Angular 1, but how to do it in Angular 4.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    <input ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
</div>


function Controller ($scope) {
    $scope.myDropDown = 'one';
}
```

[Fiddle in Angular 1](http://jsfiddle.net/EZbfM/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **`[hidden]`**

```
[hidden]="myDropDown !=='two'"
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: can u post a fiddle?

Comment: check the sample

Comment: Why down voted? I am sure the down voter have no knowledge about angular.  +1

Answer (score 4):

> `ng-show/ng-hide` does not supported for angular 2 and above. So you can use `[hidden]` as `ng-show/ng-hide` or use *ngIf as `ng-if` in above angular 2 .

try `*ngIf` instead of `ng-show`

```
<input *ngIf="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-4xc7yj?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: OP is asking for the replacement

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have update my answer. You have already answered it. That's why I am answered an another way like `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 1):

*ngIf involves manipulation of DOM.
I have seen [hidden] not working many times.
My suggestion
Create two classes hide and show

```
.hide{
visibility:hidden;
}
.show{
visibility:unset;
}
```

use [ngClass] as per your requirement.

```
[ngClass]="{'hide' : hideDiv, 'show' : !hideDiv}"
```